# How to show mail message summary on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, iphone, email

I'm writing an app that sends emails out to users.  The email itself is HTML, and consists of a little bit of styling, a link, and an image.  Since there's no user readable text in this message, when the user gets it on an iPhone, the "summary" (I'm not sure what it's actually called) shows "This message has no content".  I've tried link title and alt tags, but can't get anything to appear in the summary.

[image: iPhone mail screenshot]

Anyone have any ideas on how to make a summary show up without adding any visible text to the email message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try adding a span in the first line of your body with your desired display message and setting `display: none !important;`